# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, servlets

I need to create a tables for my image album. When i execute my code it is showing the error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis I'm not understanding what it mean. I tried same query with sql plus it was showing same error.But in sql developer table creates successfully.

```
Statement st21=con.createStatement();
StringBuilder sb21=new StringBuilder(1024);
sb21.append("create table ").append(uname).append("album(ALBUMID NUMBER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ALBUMNAME VARCHAR2(225) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT USERALBUM_PK PRIMARY KEY(ALBUMID)ENABLE);CREATE INDEX USERALBUM_INDEX ON USERALBUM (ALBUMNAME);");
String Query21=sb21.toString();
st21.executeUpdate(Query21);

Statement st2=con.createStatement();
StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder(1024);
sb2.append("create table ").append(uname).append("image(IMAGEID NUMBER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, IMAGENAME VARCHAR2(225) NOT NULL, IMAGEFULL BLOB NOT NULL, IMAGEDISC VARCHAR2(225), ALBUMID NUMBER NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT USERIMAGE_PK PRIMARY KEY(IMAGEID)ENABLE);ALTER TABLE USERIMAGE ADD CONSTRAINT USERIMAGE_USERALBUM_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(ALBUMID)REFERENCES USERALBUM(ALBUMID)ENABLE;CREATE INDEX USERIMAGE_INDEX ON USERIMAGE (IMAGENAME);");
String Query2=sb2.toString();
st2.executeUpdate(Query2);
```

Please tell me what is the error in these statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle doens't support the keyword `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4156)

Here are guides on how to simulate `AUTO_INCREMENT`ing field

- [Autoincrement Primary Key for Oracle](http://www.databaseanswers.org/sql_scripts/ora_sequence.htm)
- [Using Trigger to auto-increment field](http://www.datanamic.com/support/autoinc-oracle.html)